# Table row length in javascript show one extra

Tags: javascript

I have a table with an id of `myPicks` and when I execute the code below, the result is always one more than of the number of rows I have? Is this how it's suppose to behave? Thanks.

```
var table =document.getElementById("myPicks");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
```

Comment: Can you show your table's HTML? And what browser(s) is this (problem) happening in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a header? This could account for the extra "row"

Comment: @user132638 - Most likely yes, rows[0] would be your header.